# spring boot + JPA + mysql, unable to retrieve result set

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, jpa, microservices

i am new to spring boot, having basic knowledge of java. i am trying to build a micro-service to retrieve data from mySQL database. below are the code details.

i am able to retrieve data from the same table using standalone JDBC class. request to help.

**- Entity class**

```
package com.studentProject.entity;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Entity
@Component
@Table(name="students", schema="test_schema")
public class StudentEntity implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="id")
private Integer id;

@Column(name="name")
private String name;

@Column(name="course")
private String course;

@Column(name="country")
private String country;

@Column(name="phone")
private String phone;

public StudentEntity(Integer id, String name, String course, String country, String phone) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.course = course;
    this.country = country;
    this.phone = phone;
}

public StudentEntity() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getCourse() {
    return course;
}

public void setCourse(String course) {
    this.course = course;
}

public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}

public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}
}
```

**-Repository Class**

```
package com.studentProject.repository;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.studentProject.entity.StudentEntity;

@Repository 

public interface StudentRepository extends CrudRepository<StudentEntity, Integer> {

StudentEntity findByName(String name); 

StudentEntity findByCourse(String course);

}
```

**-Controller class**

```
package com.studentProject.controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.studentProject.entity.StudentEntity;
import com.studentProject.repository.StudentRepository;

@RestController
public class StudentController {


    @Autowired
    private StudentRepository studentRepository;

    @Autowired
    List<StudentEntity> studentList;

    public StudentController(StudentRepository studentRepository, StudentEntity studentEntity,
            List<StudentEntity> studentList) {
        super();
        this.studentRepository = studentRepository;
        this.studentList = studentList;
    }

    @GetMapping("/getStudentDetails")
    public Iterable<StudentEntity> getAllStudents(){

        return studentRepository.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/getStudentDetails/getByName")
    public StudentEntity findByName(@RequestParam(value="name") String name) {

        return studentRepository.findByName(name);
    }

    @GetMapping("/getStudentDetails/getById/{id}")
    public Optional<StudentEntity> findById(@PathVariable(value="id") Integer id) {

        return studentRepository.findById(id);
    }

    @GetMapping("/getStudentDetails/welcome")
    public String welcome() {

        return "hi brother welcome";
    }
    }
```

**-Properties File**

```
server.port = 8080
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = root
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.data.jpa.repositories.enabled=true
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = none
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

**--Pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.StudentProject</groupId>
    <artifactId>StudentProject-1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>StudentProject-1</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**-main application**

```
package com.studentProject;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class StudentProject1Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(StudentProject1Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

-mysql table details
schema=**test_schema** and table=**students**

**error details**

Comment: Can you post your Exception?

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet

Comment: Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No database selected
 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:974)
 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1024)
 at

Comment: You forgot to add the DB Name ` "jdbc:mysql://localhost/databasename";` in the properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error log

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No database selected

**it is clear that spring is not able to find database** so select database by following below.

change the `spring.datasource.url` value to below by adding database name.

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_schema
```

Comment: encountered ths error if @Component is removed. Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'studentController' defined in file [...controller\StudentController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:No qualifying bean of type 'com.studentProject.entity.StudentEntity' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.

Comment: thanks, got the result after adding the data source URL. however, what is the impact if i add @component annotation

Comment: cool...consider accept and upvote the answer if it helped you...:)

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No database selected at
```

This tells that you must select the database name, so you must add it in your config. I saw you already got an answer!

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/YOUR_DB_SCHEMA
```